# How to "queue" requests to run all the time without setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am reading data in realtime from a device through http requests, however the way I am currently doing it is, something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  for (let request of requests) {
    await request.GetData();
  }
}, 1000);
```

However, sometimes there is lag in the network, and since there are 4-5 requests, sometimes they don't all finish within a second, so they start stacking up, until the device eventually starts to timeout, so I need to somehow get rid of the setInterval. Increasing the time is not an option.

Essentially, I want them to get stuck in an infinite loop and I can add an inner timer to let the requests run again when half a second or a second has passed since the last run, but how do I get them stuck in an infinite loop without blocking the rest of the application?

Or maybe a way to make setInterval wait for all requests to finish before starting to count the 1 second interval?

Comment: You dont need `setInterval` at all. Dont fire the requests unless you get the responses of the previous one or use `Promise.all` if one each request is independent of another

Comment: Why do you need to run them all within a second? Do you want to stop running requests if a second has passed? What's the significance of a second? It's not clear what the end goal is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I dont want to run them within a second, a second is just an interval that is normally enough, but is not if there is lag. So a second is just an arbitrary number. The lower the number the more "realtime" the application feels.

Comment: Well, you state "Increasing the time is not an option." so it seemed like it was important. I would just run them as fast as they can be run and not bother with `setInterval`, but we seem to be missing some context around how `requests` is being loaded...

Comment: @HereticMonkey running them as fast as they can would put unnecessary load on the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
(async () => {
  while (true) {
    for (let request of requests) {
      await request.GetData();
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
})();
```

This will only start waiting once all the requests are finished, preventing them from stacking up.

Alternatively, on the inside of the async function, use:

```js
while (true) {
  await Promise.all(requests.map(request => request.GetData()));
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
```

This is different because all the calls to `request.GetData()` will run concurrently, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: But would that allow the rest of my application to continue running without it being blocked by the loop?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I've amended the answer, does that help?

Comment: Its not working, the setTimeout intervals are once again stacking up.

Comment: When you say 'stacking up', what do you mean exactly? That there are new calls to `GetData` before the previous ones have finished?

Comment: yes, but I had a small mistake in implementing your code, I think it is working properly now. I thought that simply adding a while(true) loop will block the rest of the app, so I havent even tried it.

Comment: Ah, but now you're using the exact code that I've given, pretty much? Just to check, because I wouldn't want this answer to confuse people reading later if it isn't completely correct.

Comment: Yes I am using the exact code (first version), there was just some leftover code that I didn't notice and remove the first time, it is working now :)